# Referencing class constants Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have a **class** which has some class **constants** and **functions** which make use of the class constants (no instance variables). pylint is returning a problem:

> Method should have "self" as the first argument

I am passing the `cls` reference into the function so to reference the constant. I didn't explicitly reference the class name as it might change (although I could use replace all to make an update).

Example:

```
def calc_size_string_kilobytes(cls, string: str) -> float:
    return len(string)/cls.BYTES_IN_KILOBYTE
```

Should this be a static function that explicitly references the class name? Like this:

```
@staticmethod
def calc_size_string_kilobytes(string: str) -> float:
    return len(string)/ClassName.BYTES_IN_KILOBYTE
```

What am I missing, I thought it was legitimate to have a class function.

Comment: Are you missing the `@classmethod` decorator?

Comment: I am, I just realised this, dumb of me. Would you like to post that as an answer and i will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are missing is the [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator, which indicates that the first argument the method receives should be the class itself.